# Rendering a CSV with pixel values to an image with PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to draw white black line picture as the raw data in CSV.
1 is black and 0 is white.

So I can modify value between 1~0 to draw gray level picture in the future.

I encounter a problem. The output picture resolution does not follow raw data.

Original raw data has 1080*2160 value between 1~0.  1*1 scale is a pixel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('python line.csv', encoding='big5')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Greys)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
```

[image: Current output]

[image: Input spreadsheet]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using matplotlib for this job? It's not really built-to-task; personally, I would use a lower-level interface like [`pypng`](https://github.com/drj11/pypng) instead -- note the `from_array` usage front-and-center in their README.

Comment: I am a beginner. Since Anaconda environment can not find PyPNG, but I will try it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that everything is fine with your code, but the size of the pyplot figure forces the irregular "bands" you are seeing in your image.

If you increase the figure size, this might help your image quality. To do that, you do `plt.figure(figsize=(10,20))` for a 10 inch x 20 inch image. The example I have below uses a smaller image, but you should be able to scale it by changing the values.

I suggest you use the Python Image Library (PIL). Here's how I would implement this with tools available in the Anaconda distribution:

```
from PIL import Image
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import random
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(200):
    #df[i] = [1 if i % 2 == 0 else 0 for i in range(100)]
    df[i] = [random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(100)]

df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)

df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

im1 = Image.new('RGBA', (200,100),'white')
pixels = []
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    for j in range(df1.shape[1]):
        c = math.floor(float(row[j])*255)
        pixels.append((c,c,c))

im1.putdata(pixels)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
imgplot = plt.imshow(im1)
```

[image]

Comment: I  modify your code and successfully draw a white black line pattern. : )

Comment: @陳信利 cool! this is one of the first things I learned to do with python